# Client side pagination not working in smart table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, smart-table

So I got a Smart-table for witch I reload the entire data-set (I need it for a graph). 
but I don't want all data to get rendered at once (got too many). So in the documentation there is something called ["Client Side Pagination"](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) but that does not seem to work for some reason. `objectDataArr[0]` holds the entire data-set

My mock up is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h1><strong>Preview Data: {{objectTranslations[objectData.LangKey]}}</strong></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table st-table="objectDataArr[0]" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="col in objectData.Tables[0].Columns" st-sort="col.Code" ng-class="{'dd-vh-2':col.Length<=25 , 'dd-vh-5':col.Length>25 && col.Length<=50, 'dd-vh-10':col.Length>50 && col.Length<=100, 'dd-vh-15':col.Length>100 && col.Length<=150, 'dd-vh-20':col.Length>150 && col.Length<=250}">{{objectTranslations[col.LangKey]}}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="col in objectData.Tables[0].Columns" ng-class="{'dd-vh-2':col.Length<=25 , 'dd-vh-5':col.Length>25 && col.Length<=50, 'dd-vh-10':col.Length>50 && col.Length<=100, 'dd-vh-15':col.Length>100 && col.Length<=150, 'dd-vh-20':col.Length>150 && col.Length<=250}">
                        <input placeholder="Search ..." st-search="col.Code" />
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in objectDataArr[0]">
                    <td ng-repeat="col in objectData.Tables[0].Columns" ng-class="{'dd-selected': row.showRowButtons == true, 'dd-vh-2':col.Length<=25 , 'dd-vh-5':col.Length>25 && col.Length<=50, 'dd-vh-10':col.Length>50 && col.Length<=100, 'dd-vh-15':col.Length>100 && col.Length<=150, 'dd-vh-20':col.Length>150 && col.Length<=250}">
                        <span class="dd-cell">{{row[col.Code]}}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                        <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="20" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that if you load your data asynchronously, which you likely do if I understand your description, you need to tell smart-table to watch the source collection so it can refresh whenever there is a change. For that you need to use the `st-safe-src`

```
<table st-safe-src="objectDataArr[0]" st-table="whateverVarYouWantToUseInTheTemplate">
   <tr ng-repeat="item in whateverVarYouWantToUseInTheTemplate"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the solution shown didn't solve my problem. could I post my code here or should I open a new question?

Answer (score 2):

If you're cool like me, you may have forgotten to pass the dependency to your app

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'smart-table'])
```